# Bug with number of close votes on summary page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The Most Close Votes tab in the tools page on serverfault (and maybe on other sites, can't get into the tools page on other sites) does not seem to be showing the correct values.

If you look at it currently, there is a question on there entitled 'What is better - 12x1 Gb RAM vs 3x4 Gb RAM?' which says it has 1 close vote, however if you go to the [question itself](https://serverfault.com/questions/121683/what-is-better-12x1-gb-ram-vs-3x4-gb-ram) it has 4 close votes.

Answer (score 3):

The 10k tools page shows the number of close votes in the selected time range (the last day, the last two days, 7 days,... depending on what you selected). The question page instead shows the total number of active close votes.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, I've noticed a different bug with that list: a question that has been *closed and reopened* will be listed under the *close votes* section with some (usually high) number of close votes, but the question page shows no current close votes.  [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/118550/anyone-know-a-windows-application-i-can-use-to-play-music-with-others-in-real-tim) is a good example (currently [top of the *most close votes* list](https://superuser.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last7days) in the 7-day view).

I can only see the tools on Super User, but I've never noticed the behavior you describe.

Comment: and yes, this should really be posted as a separate bug... blame laziness on my part.  i'll get 'round tuit later.  :)

Comment: If the close votes page shows 6 close votes it means that the questions got closed (5 votes), then reopened, and than received one more close vote. The question itself would display just the one close vote it received after being reopened. (All modulo the selected time frame)

Comment: @sth - yeah, i haven't seen that case yet, but that's what i'd expect.  maybe it makes sense on SO, where a question might be closed & reopened several times.  it just seems weird on SU, where a question might get closed but reopens are almost always a mod's doing.  i don't think many reopened questions on SU collect additional close votes.